# defines the variable in Makefile

Tags: makefile

The Makefile is written as the followings:

```
all:
        iceking='$@';
        echo $$iceking;
```

However the output is as the followings:

```
[root@localhost test]# make
iceking='all';
echo $iceking;
```

The string 'all' doesn't output. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### New sub-shell for each line of the recipe.

From [GNU make manual:](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Execution)

> When it is time to execute recipes to update a target, they are
>   executed by invoking a new sub-shell for each line of the recipe...

Set of shell commands, that called by your makefile is equivalent to:

```
bash -c iceking='all';
bash -c echo $iceking;
```

The variable `iceking` is not accessible from the environment of the second invocation of `bash`. That's why you receive empty output.

### .ONESHELL (only since GNU make 3.82)

One way to fix it, is use `.ONESHELL` special target. From [GNU make manual:](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#One-Shell)

> If the .ONESHELL special target appears anywhere in the makefile then
>   all recipe lines for each target will be provided to a single
>   invocation of the shell.

But there is one problem with `.ONESHELL`, this feature was added only since
 version 3.82 of `GNU make`.

### One line recipes.

Another way to fix it, is write recipes in one line, since all commands in the line will be passed to a single invocation of the `shell`.

```
all:
    iceking='$@'; echo $$iceking;
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks very much. The explanation is at the point.